# How to edit custom ribbon in Access 2013

Tags: ms-access, ribbon

I received an .accdb file and my task is to hide the "Home" tab on the ribbon in Access 2013. The only thing left should be the "Add-ins" tab with already present custom buttons.

I have received some advice suggesting that there might be a custom ribbon that could be edited to accomplish this. However, I have no idea where to find it and start editing. Can it be done somewhere in the design mode, or should I use Visual Studio? Can the Custom UI Editor hack an existing XML structure of an accdb?

Thanks for any input.

Comment: There is a custom ribbon XML editor here: https://github.com/fernandreu/office-ribbonx-editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule, you will find the ribbon customizations in a table called USYSRibbons.

The xml to hide home, and much everything in the ribbon would thus look like:

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">
  <ribbon startFromScratch="true">
  <officeMenu>

  <!-- First we hide all the items displayed by default -->   
  <control idMso="FileNewDatabase" visible="false"/>
  <control idMso="SourceControlCreateDatabaseFromProject" visible="false"/>
  <control idMso="FileOpenDatabase" visible="false"/>
  <control idMso="FileSave" visible="false"/>
  <control idMso="ConvertDatabaseFormat" visible="false"/>
  <control idMso="FileSaveAsMenuAccess" visible="false"/>
  <control idMso="FileManageMenu" visible="false"/>
  <control idMso="FileSendAsAttachment" visible="false"/>
  <control idMso="MenuPublish" visible="false"/>
  <control idMso="FileServerMenu" visible="false"/>
  <control idMso="FileCloseDatabase" visible="false"/>
  <control idMso="FileExit"
     getVisible="HideExit"
    getEnabled="EnableExit" />
 <!-- Now let's show a single Print Command -->
  <control idMso="FilePrintMenu" visible="false"/>  
 </officeMenu>
 </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

There is no built in editor for custom ribbons (but as noted, you can right click on ribbons and customize them).

Comment: Thank you, now I am able to wipe out what is already there, a huge step forward. However, I still don't seem to understand the XML structure enough to do exactly what I want. I tried: <control idMso="TabAddIns" visible="true"/> but to no effect

Comment: <customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">
    <ribbon>
        <tabs>
            <tab idMso="TabHomeAccess" visible="false" />
        </tabs>
    </ribbon>
</customUI> did the job. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Open the database, go to "File" in the upper left corner, then click options.
Go to the tab "Customize Ribbon", there you can deselect the main tabs.

Comment: I thought this changes your Access settings instead of the db itself?

Comment: Have you tried this method: http://www.accessribbon.de/en/?Access_-_Ribbons:Load_Ribbons_Into_The_Database:..._Using_The_System_Table_USysRibbons

Comment: That is exactly the kind of explanation I was looking for, thank you! The only thing left now is finding the exact way of hiding/showing the tabs, as indicated in my comment on Albert's XML.